# Solving Recurrence using Master Method

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

I'm trying to solve a recurrence relation to find out the complexity of an algorithm I wrote. This is the equation..

T(n) = T(n-1) + Θ(n)

And I found out the answer to O(n2), but I'm not sure if I did it right. Can someone please confirm?

Update: What if the equation is T(n) = T(n-1)+Θ(nlogn)? Will it still be O(n2)?

Comment: You're right about O(n^2), but this isn't an equation that would be solved with the master method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is O(N)+O(N-1)+...+O(1) = O(N*(N+1)/2). So yes, the total complexity is quadratic.

Comment: What if the equation is T(n) = T(n-1)+Θ(nlogn)? Will it still be O(n2)?

Comment: @user1241347: My guess is O((N^2)*log(N)). But I have not calculated that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you guess it right.

However, the form of the recurrence doesn't fit with Master method. Since you have guessed the bound correctly, substitution method is more suitable here.

Now your job is finding two constants `c` and `n0` to prove that:

`T(n) <= c*(n^2)` forall `n >= n0`

Comment: What if the equation is T(n) = T(n-1)+Θ(nlogn)? Will it still be O(n2)?

Comment: @user1241347: No, it will not. The new bound should be `O((n^2)*logn)`.